# How avoid to repeat the same command in bash script

Tags: bash, text-processing, awk

I have this bash script:

```
gunzip -c /var/log/cisco/cisco.log-$(date +%Y%m%d).gz | awk '/ath_bstuck_tasklet/ { print $4 }' | sort | uniq -c > /tmp/netgear_beacon.txt
echo "There are  `wc -l /tmp/netgear_beacon.txt | awk '{print $1}'` Stuck beacon; resetting" >> /tmp/netgear_beacon.txt

gunzip -c /var/log/cisco/cisco.log-`date +%Y%m%d`.gz | awk '/Virtual device ath0 asks to queue packet/ { print $4 }' | sort | uniq -c > /tmp/netgear_buffer_queue.txt
echo "There are  `wc -l /tmp/netgear_buffer_queue.txt | awk '{print $1}'`  routers with 'Virtual device ath0 asks to queue packet' errors" >> /tmp/netgear_buffer_queue.txt

gunzip -c /var/log/cisco/cisco.log-`date +%Y%m%d`.gz | awk '/CMS_MSG_DNSPROXY_RELOAD/ { print $4 }' | sort | uniq -c > /tmp/netgear_dns.txt
echo "There are  `wc -l /tmp/netgear_dns.txt | awk '{print $1}'`  routers with 'DNS Proxy Issue' errors" >> /tmp/netgear_dns.txt

gunzip -c /var/log/cisco/cisco.log-$(date +%Y%m%d).gz | awk '/beacon/ { print $4 }' | sort | uniq -c > /tmp/netgear_beacon_frame.txt
echo "There are  `wc -l /tmp/netgear_beacon_frame.txt | awk '{print $1}'` routers with beacon frame errors" >> /tmp/netgear_beacon_frame.txt

gunzip -c /var/log/cisco/cisco.log-$(date +%Y%m%d).gz | awk '/ACK/ { print $4 }' | sort | uniq -c | awk -v x=50 '$1 >= x' > /tmp/netgear_ACK.txt
echo "There are  `wc -l /tmp/netgear_ACK.txt | awk '{print $1}'` routers with more than 50 ACK" >> /tmp/netgear_ACK.txt
```

I would try to not repeat the `gunzip` command every time. I would run it just once and use it for all steps. I was thinking a variable, but is it the best practice?

Comment: (1) Why do you use `\`…\`` sometimes and `$(…)` others?  You know they're equivalent, right?  (2) If you run this script at 11:59PM, and it takes more than a minute to run, the date will change, and the last commands will get a different result for the `$(date +%Y%m%d)` than the first ones.  You might want to assign it to a variable at the beginning of the script.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are no "best practices". Only things that make sense and make things easier.

Extracting the common parts and parameterizing the rest is one such thing:

```
lines="`gunzip -c /var/log/cisco/cisco.log-$(date +%Y%m%d).gz`"
#gunzip would always output the same thing on the same day, so 
#just run it once and store the results in a variable
grepAndLog(){
  local regex="$1" file="$2" msg="$3" filter="${4:-cat}"
  #^names for positional parameters

  printf "%s\n" "$lines" | grep "$regex" | cut -d' ' -f4 | sort | uniq -c | eval "$filter"  > "/tmp/$file"
  local count=`wc -l < "/tmp/$file"`   
  echo "There are $count "" $msg" >> "/tmp/$file"
}
grepAndLog ath_bstuck_tasklet netgear_bacon.txt \
 'Stuck beacon; resetting'
grepAndLog netgear_buffer_queue netgear_buffer_queue.txt \
 "routers with 'Virtual device ath0 asks to queue packet' errors"
grepAndLog CMS_MSG_DNSPROXY_RELOAD netgear_dns.txt \
 " routers with 'DNS Proxy Issue' errors"
grepAndLog ath_bstuck_tasklet netgear_bacon.txt \
 " routers with beacon frame errors"
grepAndLog ACK netgear_ACK.txt \
 " routers with more than 50 ACK" 'awk -v x=50 "\$1 >= x"'
```

It's still a mainly-shell solution. But IMO more readable and over 40% shorter.

## About the code:

I'm using `grep "$regex" | cut -d' ' -f4` instead of the awk expression.
Other than that the `grepAndLog` function is a generalization of what you do in each line of your script:
You have some input (the output of gunzip), you grep that for an expression (the `$regex` parameter), and output the resulting lines, sorted and prefixed with count into a `$file`. Then you append the line count
(I do `wc -l < "$file"` instead of `wc -l "$file" | awk ...`) wrapped in a message whose beginning is constant and whose end varies (`$msg`).

In your last line you don't simply grep, but you use another filter on top of that.
Instead of creating an `if` branch for that in the function, I simply use `cat` as an implicit default additional filter in the normal cases where no fourth parameter exists (`local filter="${4:-cat}"` means create a function-local variable filter whose contents is the fourth parameter given to the function, or `cat` if no fourth parameter is provided). `cat` gets overriden if a fourth parameter is given to `grepAndLog`.

Comment: Upvoted, not just for the solution but for the first two sentences.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for that. Just one question. Whit this solution the "gunzip" process is it going to be repeated every time?

Comment: @Federi Yeah, that didn't make much sense. Fixed it.

Comment: @PSkocik Thank you! Would be veeery nice if you spend a minutes to explain me what it means :D  I guess that grepAndLog is a kind of variable repeated for what I need but I'm struggling to understand the remaining script. Thanks in advanced

Comment: @Federi An attempt at an explanation added.

Answer (score 9):

The best thing to do here would be to perform all the processing in a single `awk`. Something similar to this:

```
gunzip -c /var/log/cisco/cisco.log-$(date +%Y%m%d).gz | awk '
/ath_bstuck_tasklet/ { netgear_beakon[$4] = 1 }
/Virtual device ath0 asks to queue packet/ { netgear_buffer_queue[$4] = 1 }
...
/ACK/ { netgear_ACK[$4] ++ }
END {
  n=0; for(k in netgear_beakon) n++; print n,"Stuck beacon; resetting";
  n=0; for(k in netgear_buffer_queue) n++; print n,"routers with Virtual device ath0 asks to queue packet";
  ...
  n=0; for(k in netgear_ACK) n+=(netgear_ACK[k]>=50); print n,"routers with more than 50 ACK"
}'
```

In addition to eliminating reading the file more than once, this also eliminates the need to execute `sort` and `uniq` multiple times. This stores (or counts) each unique item in an array and then computes the number of items by iterating over the keys of each array.

Comment: It sounds interesting. If you have time,  Can you please give me a brief explanation about this script? I'm not confident yet with the language
Thanks!

Comment: @Federi -  with the missing bits added (redirect to distinct files etc) this solution will be miles ahead the other in terms of speed & efficiency.

Comment: proposed edit: 'split' doesn't do what is wanted here, and the last case needs to be handled differently by counting and testing the counts

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I'm quite sure that what you said is right, unfortunately, for level of skills, your script it looks complicate (basically, I don't know what the commands mean i.e - [$4] = 1 } or n=0 or ++). I'll google for them and I'll try to understand your script! Thanks for this!